# Accessing Entity Framework table column by index

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to 'automate' the processing of some data from a spreadsheet into a data table using C# and the Entity Framework and it would be very efficient to be able to iterate over the fields in the spreadsheet and add the data to the fields in the table record using a couple of 'for' loops. I can create a new database record using the syntax

```
CompanyData newRow = new CompanyData();
```

The problem is that I cannot access the columns in the table using an index eg.

```
newRow[a] = worksheet.Cells[a, b]?
```

Comment: I believe the issue is that Cells returns an object and you need .Value to get the value--or do some sort of concatenation & type casting. But it's been a couple of years since my .NET coding days, so I might be off here.

Comment: How are you trying to access entity framework table column by index? Do you mean access spreadsheet cells by index?

Comment: I need to access both spreadsheet and ef table using the same index.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and wanted to make sure I completed the question.

1. Using System.Reflection you can get the columns for the database as with the entity framework they are built out as an object. They are properties on the class
2. Once you have this PropertyInfo array then you can iterate through the properties. In this case I am skipping a couple of properties
3. Then you can get the values from the spreadsheet (out of the scope of this question) and put them into the field in the table. (The newRow.GetType line).

   ```
   PropertyInfo[] pi = newRow.GetType().GetProperties();
   int propLoop = pi.Length;
   for (int a = 3; a < propLoop-2; a++)
   {
       double thisvalue = 0;
       double.TryParse(worksheet.Cells[a - 1, b].RichText.Text, out thisvalue);
       newRow.GetType().GetProperty(pi[a].Name).SetValue(newRow, thisvalue);
   }
   ```

Hope this proves useful!

Comment: The order of properties returned by reflection is not stable.  You can add a custom attribute to each one to order them. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8